# Matematical notation for showing even rows of matrix

Tags: notation

I want to select an even rows of matrix. How can I show it using mathematical notations.

Something like this:

$X_{i:}$ where `i` is even.

Comment: What is the issue with your example? Also, why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

even indices:

$X_{2i}$

uneven indices can be expressed as

$X_{2i+1}$

Of course this changes the range for $i$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_{m\times n}$ be the original matrix, and $B$ be the matrix which consists of even rows of $A$. Then $B$ can be defined as follows:

$B_{i,j}=A_{2i,j}$  $\ \ (1\leq i\leq \lfloor m/2\rfloor) $